# Using Python's docx library, how can a table be indented?

Tags: python, python-docx

How can a docx table be indented? I am trying to line a table up with a tab stop set at `2cm`. The following script creates a header, some text and a table:

```
import docx
from docx.shared import Cm

doc = docx.Document()

style = doc.styles['Normal']
style.paragraph_format.tab_stops.add_tab_stop(Cm(2))

doc.add_paragraph('My header', style='Heading 1')
doc.add_paragraph('\tText is tabbed')

# This indents the paragraph inside, not the table
# style = doc.styles['Table Grid']
# style.paragraph_format.left_indent = Cm(2)

table = doc.add_table(rows=0, cols=2, style="Table Grid")

for rowy in range(1, 5):
    row_cells = table.add_row().cells

    row_cells[0].text = 'Row {}'.format(rowy)
    row_cells[0].width = Cm(5)

    row_cells[1].text = ''
    row_cells[1].width = Cm(1.2)

doc.save('output.docx')
```

It produces a table with no ident as follows:

[image: no indent]

How can the table be indented as follows?
(preferably without having to load an existing document):

[image: Desired output]

If for example `left-indent` is added to the `Table Grid` style (by uncommenting the lines), it will be applied at the paragraph level, not the table level resulting in the following (which is not wanted):

[image: indented at paragraph level]

In Microsoft Word, this can be done on the table properties by entering `2.0 cm` for `Indent from left`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Fred C's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54699631/2311167), I came up with this solution:

```
from docx.oxml import OxmlElement
from docx.oxml.ns import qn

def indent_table(table, indent):
    # noinspection PyProtectedMember
    tbl_pr = table._element.xpath('w:tblPr')
    if tbl_pr:
        e = OxmlElement('w:tblInd')
        e.set(qn('w:w'), str(indent))
        e.set(qn('w:type'), 'dxa')
        tbl_pr[0].append(e)
```

Comment: Where `indent` is in twips, e.g. 1cm is about 569

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not yet supported by `python-docx`. It looks like this behavior is produced by the `w:tblInd` child of the `w:tbl` element. It's possible you could develop a workaround function to add an element like this using `lxml` calls on the `w:tbl` element, which should be available on the `._element` attribute of a `Table` object.

You can find examples of other workaround functions by searching on 'python-docx workaround function' and similar ones by searching on 'python-pptx workaround functions'.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I will investigate the workarounds. Currently I have given most things a `-Cm(2.0)` left indent and increased the left page margin accordingly.

Comment: Is there also a possibility to change a table indention on the right side? I read this can be done with paragraphs. My aim is to have a negative indention, so the table ends on the right of the right page margin.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it:

```
import docx
import lxml
mydoc = docx.Document()            
mytab = self.mydoc.add_table(3,3)
nsmap=mytab._element[0].nsmap # For namespaces
searchtag='{%s}tblPr' % nsmap['w'] # w:tblPr
mytag='{%s}tblInd' % nsmap['w'] # w:tblInd
myw='{%s}w' % nsmap['w'] # w:w
mytype='{%s}type' % nsmap['w'] # w:type
for elt in mytab._element:
    if elt.tag == searchtag:
        myelt=lxml.etree.Element(mytag)
        myelt.set(myw,'1000')
        myelt.set(mytype,'dxa')
        myelt=elt.append(myelt)
```